# What's the word for "doing useless things while you don't have anything to do"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Can anybody tell me what the word for "doing useless things while you don't have anything to do" is?

Let's say I am surfing on the web, reading some articles, etc. while I don't have anything to do.  It is not computer related. I am looking for a broad term.

I've checked the synonyms of "killing time" and these are what I've found:

- dawdle
- hang around
- idle
- kill time
- **lark**: (v) play boisterously
- mess around
- play around

It seems *lark* can work for this case.

Comment: Related to this is [Procrastination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrastination), which is to waste time on unimportant things whilst there is something important that could be being done instead.

Comment: Regarding the synonyms for *killing time*:  Actually, *lark* doesn't work at all.  Well, you *could* kill time by larking, but by and large people kill time in ways that are neither boisterous nor prankish.

Comment: I am not an English native speaker but I once heard the expression "to drift" and it was explained to me that it meant "to kill time" or something similar. The person who used it is from Northern Ireland. Does anyone know this expression?

Comment: what's wrong with "to kill time"?

Comment: @Louis Rhys: it gets you into jail

Comment: We used to say "dossing" at school.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Killing time* is a common idiom for this kind of activity.

Example (from Dictionary.com definition 51 of [time](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/time)): *While I was waiting, I killed time counting the cars on the freight trains.*

Sometimes it carries the connotation that you have something better to do that you could be doing, but it is definitely used in this sense as well, as in the example.

Comment: +1. I was about to say *procrastinating* but that's not right.

Answer (score 11):

I use the word *diddle* or *diddle away*. I've also heard *putter*, as in: **My grandfather likes to putter in the garden**. Merriam-Webster online seems to support the definitions:

*diddle*: fiddle, toy —usually used with *with*

*putter*: : 1. to move or act aimlessly or idly  2.to work at random : tinker

And, I guesss tinker might work too.

Comment: *Putter* is much more apt than *diddle* or *tinker*.  (See Monica Cellio's answer.  Yes, I realize hers was a minute later.)

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- I didn't see the "this page has been updated" notice this time.

Comment: In the UK this is called "pottering" - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potter_about

Answer (score 6):

"Twiddling one's thumbs" comes to mind.

Related, but more towards doing something that appears to be useful instead of the actual job is "pencil sharpening".

Comment: Also there is "yak shaving" which has slightly different connotations. http://projects.csail.mit.edu/gsb/old-archive/gsb-archive/gsb2000-02-11.html

Comment: @Dan: I like it!

Answer (score 5):

For one word, you could say one is *idling* or being [*idle*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idle):

> to spend time doing nothing important

Comment: But I am doing something even though it is useless. `idle` means doing nothing according to the link.

Comment: I updated the link. It means doing nothing important--"nothing" as in "not work"

Answer (score 5):

I up-voted "killing time", but for a single word I've also heard "puttering" (or sometimes "puttering around").

From [here](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=putter&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=Om5uTrTcHcuRgQe8je3nAg&ved=0CBgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=362d883fe9982186&biw=996&bih=1030):

> 1. Occupy oneself in a desultory but pleasant manner, doing a number of small tasks or not concentrating on anything particular
>
>    - early morning is the best time of the day to putter around in the garden
> 2. Move or go in a casual, unhurried way
>
>    - the duck putters on the surface of the pond

Comment: I usually hear "putter about" rather than "putter" on its own.

Comment: I kinda like the word `putter` :) Thanks for the word.

Comment: @Monica: While your one-word answer is contained in Brian's entry and appeared a minute later, yours is still better because (1) the presentation is better, and (2) it isn't cluttered by words that are *less* appropriate than *putter*.  (And (3) I agree that "killing time" is the single best answer to the original question.)

Answer (score 3):

One that's commonly used in Australia, is "mucking around" (often ["Muck about"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muck_about)):

> (intransitive) To do random unplanned work or spend time idly

Comment: Nice to know. +1

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using: -- 'I whiled away the time surfing some articles on the web'.
          -- 'I frittered away time surfing the Internet'.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of browsing around, there is "wilfing", short for "What was I Looking For?" But its more apt when you are putting off more important work.

http://labnol.blogspot.com/2007/04/word-of-day-wilfing-what-was-i-looking.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**doodle**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/doodle).

> **doodle**: *US* to kill time

*I sat and [doodled](http://0v3r473dblog.blogspot.fr/2009/11/musings-from-english-class.html) counting machines*.